# How remove Attribute xlmns after document.CreateElement?

Tags: javascript, svg, createelement

I try to add text to *SVG* file in my function

```
var newText = SvgDoc.createElement("text");
newText.setAttribute( "x", 10);
newText.setAttribute("y", 10);
newText.setAttribute("font-size", 10);
newText.setAttribute("id", "newText");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello world");
newText.appendChild(textNode);
SvgDoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(newText);
```

but it doesn't work because `SvgDoc.createElement` adds empty attribute xlmns = "" in tag text.

For deleting attribute xlmns   I used `newText.removeAttribute("xmlns")`; but it doesn't work.

Another way to add text to *Svg* file it's using `SvgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");` but I don't understand  why needs this const string for creating any element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: From document Note the namespace declaration only needs to be provided once on a root tag. The declaration defines the default namespace, so the user agent knows that all the <svg> tag's descendant tags also belong to the same namespace.

Comment: In markup yes, when creating with javascript you have no ancestors at the point of creation.

Comment: It's reason why i have to delete empty attribute xlmns.

Comment: I've no idea what you meant by that last comment. You need to use createElementNS to create SVG elements per the document I linked in my first comment.

Comment: New element adds to SVG file if  I create element with xlmns = http://www.w3.org/2000/svg or delete attribute xlmns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118994/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-askeet).